# Яндекс.Касса - получение уведомления

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

никак не могу вкурить, что я должен выловить в на URI, указанном для уведомлений.
Платежи проходят, вот такой код

```
require_once '../nxServ.php';
```

`$adm=new nxAdm();`

`$adm->logYa('callBack');`

исправно отрабатывает и пишет в БД лог ('callBack')
Однако, ответ от яндекса - это что будет? где искать?
$_POST[0] - не катит, null.
куда курить?

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

видимо, веб-сокеты? ибо работает